# Do you receive Trading Cards at set intervals?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

When playing a Steam game that supports Trading Cards, you can receive a certain amount of trading cards which you can use to craft badges or sell on the Steam Market.

Does Steam give away these cards randomly, or do they give it away at set intervals (Ex. every hour a new card is given)?

Comment: Definitely randomly.

Comment: Also related: [How often do trading cards drop?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123807/how-often-do-trading-cards-drop)